# apache2 Allow access to subdirectory

Tags: django, wordpress, apache2, passenger

I am currently running a Django site on Dreamhost using Passenger. I would like to run a Wordpress blog in the 'public' directory that currently holds my static files (which is where I assume it should live). Since Django currently owns all of /*, I was told I would need to add a Location entry to the httpd.conf of my apache2 server. I tried both Location and Directory and could not get them to work. The code snippet below is basically what I typed in a bunch of different ways.

```
<Directory /home/user/domain/public/blog/>
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also tried adding AllowOverride All to try and catch the htaccess file in the blog folder but no dice. I am extremely new to messing with apache (first time), can anyone point me in the right direction to get /blog/ to show the wordpress site and not a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to my problem was identifying how to override Passenger, which is what is running the Django app. Access your httpd.conf file. Within the main Virtualhost section (the one that defines your domain and how the public folder is handled) place this code to override Passenger and Django's grip on the /* directory.

```
Alias /blog /home/user/domain/public/blog

<Directory /home/user/domain/public/blog>
PassengerEnabled off
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Adding `PassengerEnabled off` takes care of Passenger and allows the Directory to be served outside of the Django app. I don't think AllowOverride or Allow from all does much of anything but I left it in just to be safe. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Awesome, glad you found it! Thanks for finishing out the thread. If I ever go to dreamhost, I will know this little tidbit.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an Apache Alias directive:

```
Alias /blog/  /home/user/domain/public/blog/
```

That 'Alias' will along with your 'Directory' directive should do the trick.

**Note**: I have these listed before my wsgi configuration that loads django into apache. ( I dont know if that matters tho, but it might.)

**Edit:**
In my main httpd. conf file I

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

I assume there are 'DocumentRoot' and 'Directory' directives in there.

Next: in my virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /blog/  /home/user/domain/public/blog/

<FilesMatch \.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png|ico)$>
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch \.(?i:css|jst|js|txt|htm|html)$>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /home/user/domain/public/blog/>
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

Maybe my FilesMatch directives were actually doing the magic ( I might have missed that before)

**Debugging**
If you cant get this going, you might want to enable more verbose httpd logging output in apache to see if you can get it to tell you what it is unhappy about.
you do this by changing the 'LogLevel' directive from 'warn' to debug

```
LogLevel debug
```

now

```bash
tail -f /path/to/you/apache/error_logs
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Tried but no dice. I added it before the /home/user/domain/public directory since I didn't find any wsgi configs. Could I be missing a specific directive that overrides django's stranglehold on the public folder?

Comment: I edited my original answer to include the 'FilesMatch' directives, hopefully that will do the trick. Note I am not using dreamhost, but that should not really matter.. Apache is apache. Also I did not understand your reference to 'Dreamhost -> Passenger'. I tried to see how they were letting you modify your httpd config but I could not. I am assuming that you are running a virtual server and have complete control of a virtual server.

Comment: Passenger is a module Dreamhost provides to easily deploy Rails/Python apps. I think it is the reason why I don't have a wsgi_module in my conf file. It may serve as an alternative. I am trying out your solution but I'm having no luck moving it forward. The error logs may be the next step. You are correct, I am running a virtual server, and I am placing these code snippets inside the main virtualhost section that handles the domain I am trying to add the blog to.

Comment: to complete this thread I feel compelled to mention. That django has several https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/ and blogging plugins https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/